# Validating mobile number - Odoo

Tags: python, odoo

In my xml file, i have the below field under a tree structure.

```
<field name="phone"/>
```

I have the below group under the form structure

```
<group>
<field name="phone" onchange="validate_phone(phone)" placeholder="Enter your mobile number"/>
</group>
```

In my python file:

```py
    @api.depends('phone')
    @api.onchange('phone')
    def validate_phone(self):
        if self.phone:
            match = re.match('^[0-9]\d{10}$', self.phone)
            if match == None:
               raise ValidationError('Invalid')
```

There will be no error in code but still it does not work.
Could any one help me to get through this?

Comment: That matches a string of 11 digits.  Is that what you want?

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is your friend when it comes to validating your regex string

Comment: could you please let me know to check the matches a string of 10 digits! @Tim Roberts

Comment: Umm, you have a string of 10 digits in there after a single digit.  Use  `r'^\d{10}$'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is no need to use **`onchange`** attribute in xml keep it simple like

```
<group>
    <field name="phone" placeholder="Enter your mobile number"/>
</group>
```

Second try this on just using **`onchange`** decorator

```
@api.onchange('phone')
def validate_phone(self):
    if self.phone:
        match = re.match('^[0-9]\d{10}$', self.phone)
        if not match:
           raise ValidationError('Invalid')
```